i'm having a problem using Survey package in R, i coded a prop an cv function but its returning different results for the same svytotal results
library(survey)

    wrap.table3 = function(SVYres, Niv1, Niv2, Niv3) {
        Tabela = array(SVYres, dim = c(length(Niv1), length(Niv2), length(Niv3)))
        TabCV = array(cv(SVYres), dim = c(length(Niv1), length(Niv2), length(Niv3)))

        dimnames(Tabela) = dimnames(TabCV) = list(Niv1, Niv2, Niv3)
        Total12 = apply(Tabela, c(1, 2), sum)
        TabProp12 = Total12
            for(i in 1:nrow(TabProp12)){
                TabProp12[i,] = TabProp12[i,] / sum(TabProp12[i,])
            }
        TabProp12 = TabProp12 * 100
        Total13 = apply(Tabela, c(1, 3), sum)
        TabProp13 = Total13
            for(i in 1:nrow(TabProp13)){
                TabProp13[i,] = TabProp13[i,] / sum(TabProp13[i,])
            }
        TabProp13 = TabProp13 * 100
        Total23 = apply(Tabela, c(2, 3), sum)
        TabProp23 = Total23
            for(i in 1:nrow(TabProp23)){
                TabProp23[i,] = TabProp23[i,] / sum(TabProp23[i,])
            }
        TabProp23 = TabProp23 * 100
        Total = sum(Tabela)
        TabPropt = Tabela / Total
        TabPropt = TabPropt * 100
        cross_tab_by_Niv1 = list()
            for (nivel1 in Niv1) {
                sub_Tabela = Tabela[nivel1, , ]
                sub_TabCV = TabCV[nivel1, , ]
                sub_Prop = sub_Tabela
    
                for (i in 1:nrow(sub_Prop)) {
                    sub_Prop[i, ] = sub_Prop[i, ] / sum(sub_Prop[i, ])
                }
                sub_Prop = sub_Prop * 100
    
                cross_tab_by_Niv1[[nivel1]] = list(
                "Tabela cruzada - Total" = sub_Tabela,
                "Coeficientes de Variação - Total" = round(sub_TabCV * 100, 2),
                "CV simples" = sub_TabCV < 0.15,
                "Proporção" = round(sub_Prop, 2))
            }
 
        Lista = list(
            "Tabela cruzada - Total" = Tabela,
            "Coeficientes de Variação - Total" = round(TabCV * 100, 2),
            "CV simples" = TabCV < 0.15,
            "Tabela cruzada - Proporção (Niv1 e Niv2)" = round(TabProp12, 2),
            "Tabela cruzada - Proporção (Niv1 e Niv3)" = round(TabProp13, 2),
            "Tabela cruzada - Proporção (Niv2 e Niv3)" = round(TabProp23, 2),
            "Tabela cruzada - Proporção (total)" = round(TabPropt, 2),
            "Análise por nível 1" = cross_tab_by_Niv1)
  
    return(Lista)
}

This function receives a svytotal table (SVYres) and Niv 1 to 3 are levels from my svy_design data frame, the issue here is this:
$`Tabela cruzada - Total`
First analyses:
, , no
       1               2                 3
a      8765131.5 ___      82969.05   ___       685473.9
b      173841.4     ___   815686.98  ___       9143113.7
c      515572.1  ___      21597136.77    ___   310602.3
d      19985487.1 ___  457899.20   ___  150929.0

, , yes
       1            2              3
a      2050197.6___    57963.94___       83893.166
b      113054.4___     185841.57___      876623.652
c      88252.4 ___     2830886.94___     82802.989
d      5352426.3___    138895.23___      8017.146

second analyses:
$`Tabela cruzada - Total`
, , no
        1            2              3
a       8765131.5 ___   58561.36  ___     838405.9
b       152980.9 ___    840094.67   ___   9143113.7
c       536432.6   ___  21597136.77   ___ 236246.8
d       19985487.1 ___  304967.11  ___    225284.5

, , yes
        1            2              3
a       2050197.65 ___  34388.84   ___    121277.80
b       80489.54    ___ 209416.67  ___    876623.65
c       120817.2   ___  2830886.94  ___   75936.24
d       5352426.29 ___  101510.60    ___  14883.90

Imagine in the first analyses I compared 4 diferent groups of people, and I analysed the first and second with the data provided by my table, but the third I had to group the other 2 groups left.
When I analysed the second time, I changed the second and third column but did not changed the first, however the results from my first column changed as well, supposedly they were to be the same!
I suspect this probably have an error regarding a loop or probably that does not make sense
The svytotal estimates are the same for the 1 column values im my array, so they should be the same in both cases. (notice that the first and fourth line from my output are the same, the real problem are the second and third).
here is an example whith:
library(survey)
data(api)

dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)

VARJ = dclus1$variables
VARJ$stype = as.factor(VARJ$stype) 
dclus1$variables=VARJ

VARJ = dclus1$variables
VARJ$stypeC=ifelse(VARJ$stype=="E","E",
    ifelse(VARJ$stype=="H" | VARJ$stype=="M","HM","none"))

VARJ$stypeC = as.factor(VARJ$stypeC) 
dclus1$variables=VARJ

VARJ = dclus1$variables
VARJ$sch.wide = as.factor(VARJ$sch.wide) 
dclus1$variables=VARJ

VARJ = dclus1$variables
VARJ$comp.imp = as.factor(VARJ$comp.imp) 
dclus1$variables=VARJ


Tabela = svytotal(x=~interaction(stype,sch.wide,comp.imp),  
dclus1, na.rm=TRUE)
wrap.table3 (Tabela,levels(dclus1$variables$sch.wide), 
    levels(dclus1$variables$stype), 
    levels(dclus1$variables$comp.imp))

Tabela = svytotal(x=~interaction(stypeC,sch.wide,comp.imp),  
dclus1, na.rm=TRUE)
wrap.table3 (Tabela,levels(dclus1$variables$sch.wide), 
    levels(dclus1$variables$stypeC), 
    levels(dclus1$variables$comp.imp))


hi Renan!  would it be possible for you to narrow this example down a bit?  it would be great if you could also provide an example that uses publicly available data, so that people trying to help can reproduce the problem on our own computers.  if you type ?svytotal the bottom of the help page has some toy datasets that might be useful for this..  thanks!

sure, just adited it, there is a exemple using data(api), the problem persists, E column is changing in line 2 when its supposed to be the same

hi, thanks for adding the public data!  this example still seems much larger than necessary..  is it possible for you to narrow this question quite a bit?  running your code produces 16 tables..  is it possible for you to narrow your example so it's a bit more precise and readable?  thank you!!

Hello @RenanReis. I did not completely follow your question, but here is a possible solution, using the surveytable package:
library(surveytable)
set_survey(dclus1, opts = "general")
var_cross("tmp", "sch.wide", "comp.imp")
tab_cross("stype", "tmp")

Is this something similar to what you are looking for?
